# "tasksel: aptitude failed (100)" installing LAMP on Ubuntu (vagrant)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, lamp, vagrant

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo tasksel install lamp-server
tasksel: aptitude failed (100)
```

I'm hoping to get a LAMP server from a clean install of ubuntu.  All the googles suggest tasksel, which going into a pretty ascii gui, downloads stuff, then dies with this message.

I'm guessing I should try doing it via `apt-get` of the individual packages but seems a fair chance somebody else is going to search for this error message and want the right answer.

Comment: just run "tasksel" as root or sudo without any options, does it start and give you a menu from whence to select the different tasks?

Answer (score 1):

aptitude failed because it is out-of-date or some such. Ensure you're open to the internet and

```
 sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

then try tasksel again.